# select elements who has no id in an html page

Tags: javascript

I have multiple buttons in my HTML, and I only want to select those who hasn't and id attribute.

To select all buttons I use this script, which returns all buttons :

```
var buttonNodesList = document.querySelectorAll('button');
```

I googled about it, and I found that to get all buttons who has an id, I've to use a script like this :

```
var buttonNodesList = document.querySelectorAll('button[id]');
```

So isn't there any method to return thos buttons who has no id ?

Answer (score 3):

In many modern browsers you can use [:not](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation):

```
var buttonNodesList = document.querySelectorAll('button:not([id])');
```

If you want wider browser support, you can use something like this:

```
var buttonNodesList = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('button'),0)
  .filter( function(button) {
    return button.getAttribute('id') === null;
  });
```

Which leaves you with an array, rather than a NodeList and supports the most browsers only if you have a [shim for filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility).

Comment: What's the point of dancing around with `filter`? E.g. IE 8 and below doesn't support `:not()` selector indeed, but it doesn't support `filter` either.

Comment: @Pavlo You can't really shim `:not()`, but it's easy to shim `filter` and most developer's should be doing that by now, if they want to write scripts that work on browsers like IE 8.